# Text Analysis: extracting person name and quotation: how to create a pattern

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, data-science, python-re

I need to extract a name and a quote for a given text such as:

> Homer Simpson said: "Okay, here we go..."

The returned values:

> - extracted_person_name - The extracted person name, as appearing in the patterns explained above
> - extracted_quotation   - The extracted quoted text (withot the surrounding quotation marks).
>
> - Important Note: if the pattern is not found, return None values for both the 
>   extracted person name and the extracted text.

You could expect the input text to look similar to the following pattern:

> Person name said: "quoted text"

Variations of the above pattern:

> The colon punctuation mark (:) is optional, and and might not appear
> in the input sentence. Instead of the word said you could also expect
> the words:
>
> answered, responded, replied

**this is what I got so far:**

```
def person_quotation_pattern_extraction(raw_text):
    
    name_pattern = "\w+\s\w+"
    quote_pattern = "["]\w+["]"
    
    quote = re.search(quote_pattern, raw_text)
    name = re.search(name_pattern, raw_text)

    
    if re.search(quote_pattern,raw_text):
        extracted_quotation = quote.group(0) 
    else:
        extracted_quotation=None

    if re.search(name_pattern,raw_text):
        extracted_person_name = name.group(0)
    else:
        extracted_person_name=None

    return extracted_person_name, extracted_quotation
```

**problem is it returns `Null`. I'm assuming the patterns are incorrect can you tell me what's wrong with them?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first pattern is all right. It matches "Homer Simpson" as well as "here we" but since you only return group 0 this is fine.

The second pattern has some issues. Since you open the string with `"` and use the same `"` inside the string, python thinks the string ended there. You can observe this from the colors of the characters changing from green (strings) to black (not strings) back to green.

```
quote_pattern = "["]\w+["]"
```

You can prevent this by starting (and ending) your string with single quotation marks `'` like this:

```
quote_pattern ='["]\w+["]'
```

However, this does still not match the provided quote. This is because `\w` matches any word character (equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_]) but does *not* match the comma `,`, the points `.` or the whitespaces  .
Therefore you could change the pattern to

```
quote_pattern ='["].*["]'
```

Where `.*` matches anything.
You can further simplify the expression by removing the square brackes. They are not needed in this case since they contain only one element.

```
quote_pattern ='".*"'
```

You need to return the quote without the surrounding quotation marks. Therefore you can create a capure group in the expression using `()`:

```
quote_pattern ='"(.*)"'
```

This way the quotations marks are still needed to match but a group is created which does not contain them. This group is going to have index `1` instead of the `0` you use at the moment:

```
extracted_quotation = quote.group(1)
```

This should lead to the desired result.

Check out this website for some interactive regex action: https://regex101.com/